# Как установить .NET FRAMEWORK без взаимодействия пользователя?

Tags: c++

Как установить .NET FRAMEWORK без взаимодействия пользователя?
То есть программа проверяет если на PC не установлен .NET FRAMEWORK, то устанавливает его без взаимодействия пользователя т.е пользователь ничего не видит и не нажимает, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Установка .NET требует админских привелегий. Боюсь что никак. Возможно как-то можно кусок NET забрать, загрузить библиотеку и передать в NET управление.

Comment: Если целиться на актульные версии, то они гарантировано имеются в системе. Если требуется поддержка устаревших систем и / или версий, то без привилегий администратора не обойтись.